# Better way of writing Javascript code

Tags: javascript

I was wondering the best way to write the code.

**Scenario 1:**

```
function main() {
  var arr = [];
  performSomeLogic(arr);
}

function performSomeLogic(arr) {
     var sum = 0;

     for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
        // some more logic
     }

     for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
        // some other logic
     }
}
```

**scenario 2:**

```
function main() {
  var arr = [];
  performSomeLogic(arr);
}

function performSomeLogic(arr) {
    var sum = 0;
    sum = commonLoop(true, arr);
    sum = commonLoop(false, arr);
}

function commonLoop(flag, arr) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
        if(flag){
           // some more logic
         } else {
            // some other logic
         }
     }
     return sum;
}
```

As you can see in the first scenario we have only 2 functions (main and performSomeLogic) and in the second scenario we have 3 functions and the code has been modularised (main, performSomeLogic and commonLoop).

Which way of coding is better?

Comment: Do you need reset `sum` to zero in first scenario?

Comment: first one is more readable, the overall complexity of both the function are same + in second approach you have extra if-else condition for every iteration

Comment: I would like to break code to `functions`

Comment: Use a boolean variable for choosing behavior of your code is always a bed idea: reader of this piece of code cannot understand what the parameter mean, and you will soon get into trouble if you want a third condition.

Comment: I don't see why you can't just do `some more logic` and `some other logic` in the same loop. But other than that I'd use scenario 1 unless `commonLoop()` can get utilized elsewhere. If its not reused then its your personal preference.

Comment: Coding should be like chemistry in that you want useful molecules of code; not a big messy mixure of everything, and not a huge set of individual elements.

Answer (score 2):

I think that a method should do a single thing where possible. Keep your methods so that you can convey better meaning to the individual steps.
I feel this makes your main method a lot cleaner and more readable, though admittedly It's probably a lot more verbose.

```
function main() {
  var arr = [];
  var sum;
  sum += performFirstLogic(arr);
  sum += performSecondLogic(arr);
}

function performFirstLogic(arr) {
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
    // some more logic
  }

 return sum;
}

function performSecondLogic(arr) {
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
    // some more logic
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Depending on the circumstances, I may find the opportunity to pass functions around to make things easier.

```
function main() {
  var arr = [];
  var sum;
  sum += processLoop(arr, firstLogic);
  sum += processLoop(arr, secondLogic);
}

function processLoop(arr, customLogic) {
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
    customLogic(arr[i]);
  }

 return sum;
}

function firstLogic(data) {
  //First lot of logic
}

function secondLogic(data) {
  //First lot of logic
}
```

Your milage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: Depends

Long Answer:

What does the code do?  Is the logic occuring in the loop tightly related?  Is it a separate task altogether?

Consider the following version:

**Scenario 1 (Changed)**

```
function main() {
  var arr = [];
  performSomeLogic(arr);
}

function performSomeLogic(distinctData, uniqueData) {
     var sum = 0;

     sum += clearlyPerformDistinctTask(distinctData);

     sum += clearlyPerformUniqueTask(uniqueData);
}

function clearlyPerformDistinctTask(arr) {

     for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
        // some more logic
     }

     return sum;
}


function clearlyPerformUniqueTask(arr) {

     for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
        // some more logic
     }

     return sum;
}
```

It's all about READABILITY!  Break smaller tasks into functions that say EXACTLY and only what they do.  Its better to move distinct logic into its own neat little box, don't clutter your code!  Everything can't be one giant procedure!

If two loops perform totally different tasks, don't lump them together and switch between parameters if its not clear and related logic!

However, if the logic tightly related:

**Scenario 2 (Changed)**

```
function main() {
  var arr = [];
  performSomeLogic(arr);
}

function performSomeLogic(data) {
     var sum = 0;

     sum += clearlyPerformTaskWithOptions(data, { sumType: "X"});
     sum += clearlyPerformTaskWithOptions(data, { sumType: "Y"});
}

function clearlyPerformTask(arr, options) {

     for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (options.sumType == "X")
            sum += arr[i];
        else if (options.sumType == "Y")
            sum += 2 * arr[i];
        else
            sum -= 4;
        // some more logic
     }

     return sum;
}
```

Does it make sense to group your logic together?  Is the data set used the same?  Does it acheive the same role but by different means?  Does it make sense when you read it?

These are all questions you must consider when organizing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing because it's unclear what you are trying to do and why, but you might find some use for the [reduce method on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) here:

```
function main() {
  var arr = [];
  var sum = arr.reduce(sumAndDoLogic, 0);
  // do stuff with sum
}

function sumAndDoLogic(sum, currentValue) {
  if (/* something about currentValue */) {
    // do some logic
  } else {
    // do some different logic
  }
  return sum + currentValue;
}
```